# How can I get my ZSH terminal to load Libx11 on OSX 10.10 Yosemite?!? FFcast install

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite

I am trying and trying to install ffcast on my computer, however in order to be succesful i need to have libx11 installed and active.

I have quartz, Xcode, and commandline installed, however i keep getting the same problem

```
in ~/Desktop/teeeest
❯ git clone --recursive https://github.com/lolilolicon/FFcast.git
Cloning into 'FFcast'...
remote: Counting objects: 651, done.
remote: Total 651 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (651/651), 154.72 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (379/379), done.
Checking connectivity... done
Submodule 'src/xrectsel' (https://github.com/lolilolicon/xrectsel.git) registered for path 'src/xrectsel'
Cloning into 'src/xrectsel'...
remote: Counting objects: 32, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (17/17), done.
remote: Total 32 (delta 13), reused 32 (delta 13)
Unpacking objects: 100% (32/32), done.
Checking connectivity... done
Submodule path 'src/xrectsel': checked out 'f61bf80b8a0605496a8009852e530d86ded765c6'
5s

 in ~/Desktop/teeeest
❯ cd FFcast && ./bootstrap && ./configure --enable-xrectsel ... && make ...
autoreconf: Entering directory `.'
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext
autoreconf: running: aclocal
autoreconf: configure.ac: tracing
autoreconf: configure.ac: adding subdirectory src/xrectsel to autoreconf
autoreconf: Entering directory `src/xrectsel'
autoreconf: configure.ac: creating directory build-aux
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Libtool
autoreconf: running: /usr/local/Cellar/autoconf/2.69/bin/autoconf
autoreconf: running: /usr/local/Cellar/autoconf/2.69/bin/autoheader
autoreconf: running: automake --add-missing --copy --no-force
configure.ac:4: installing 'build-aux/compile'
configure.ac:3: installing 'build-aux/install-sh'
configure.ac:3: installing 'build-aux/missing'
Makefile.am: installing 'build-aux/depcomp'
autoreconf: Leaving directory `src/xrectsel'
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Autoheader
configure.ac:5: installing 'build-aux/install-sh'
configure.ac:5: installing 'build-aux/missing'
doc/Makefile.am:11: warning: '%'-style pattern rules are a GNU make extension
src/Makefile.am:12: warning: '%'-style pattern rules are a GNU make extension
autoreconf: Leaving directory `.'
configure: WARNING: you should use --build, --host, --target
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... build-aux/install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for pod2man... /usr/bin/pod2man
checking for ./src/xrectsel/xrectsel.c... yes
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating aux/zsh_completion/Makefile
config.status: creating doc/Makefile
config.status: creating src/Makefile
=== configuring in src/xrectsel (/Users/Dimitrie/Desktop/teeeest/FFcast/src/xrectsel)
configure: running /bin/sh ./configure --disable-option-checking '--prefix=/usr/local'  '--enable-xrectsel' '...' 'build_alias=...' 'host_alias=...' 'target_alias=...' --cache-file=/dev/null --srcdir=.
configure: WARNING: you should use --build, --host, --target
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... build-aux/install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for ...-gcc... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for library containing XOpenDisplay... no
configure: error: libx11 is required
configure: error: ./configure failed for src/xrectsel
```

the same problem only for linux is displayed here [superuser link](https://superuser.com/questions/849193/compiling-ffcast-for-ubuntu-14-04-libx11-is-required?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter)

Help is appreciated!

Comment: You might be able to install libx11 via [macports](http://macports.org).

Comment: This has nothing to do with zsh or the terminal. FFcast seems to need *libx11* for its compilation. But it cannot be found on your system, as in: it is not on your hard disk or at least not where it can be found by FFcast's `configure` script.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! So what exactly is libx11, i thought is was quartz. But i am not sure.. How do i install it. And how do i configure it correctly?

Comment: I would rather not install it with macports as it gives problens with other cli sometimes

Comment: installed macports and installed xorg-libX11, still get the same issue! :( how hard can it be to use ffcast

Comment: or what should i do to the configure script in order to let it look towards the right directory for libx11?